# ToDo list, with SPECIFIC repeat option

Tags: to-do-list

I'm looking for a simple to-do list, that preferably is cloud-synced. I'd like something with a relatively light-weight, simple interface, similar to Any.Do or #fetchnotes. I was using [CheckMark Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greenbeansoft.Checkmark), but it is really WAY overkill for what I want.

My biggest criteria is that I want to be able to set a task to repeat, some interval **from the date it is completed**. Most of them let you repeat every 6 months or 2 weeks or whatever, from the due date. But take this example:

Task with due date of 5/30. 
Task set to repeat every 6 months from completion.
I *complete* the task, marking it done, on 5/13. 
The next occurrence should now repeat 6 months from 5/13 (the completion date), not from 5/30 (the original due date).

And of course whatever reminder is set (2 weeks for example) should be relative to the new due date, 5/13 in the example above.

Most of the one's I've looked at either are not cloud-synced. And I've not found any others than CheckMark Pro that allow the next occurrence to repeat based on COMPLETION date rather than DUE date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[todolist](https://en.todoist.com/)

https://support.todoist.com/hc/en-us/articles/205325931-Dates-and-Times

Recurring dates -  e.g. Clean fridge with due date every! 3 months starting 10 April

Answer (score 4):

[Astrid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.timsu.astrid) has support for scheduled reminders based on [completion date](http://blog.astrid.com/repeating-tasks-demystified/).

Cloud support is also present - tasks sync with astrid.com

[image: reminder]

Also [Remember The Milk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/) allows a user to schedule due dates depending on the completion of a task - [one needs to enter](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/basics/repeatformat.rtm) "after x days" instead of "every x days". [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rememberthemilk.MobileRTM) and iOS apps available.

Comment: Stupid, I know, but boy does that Astrid icon irk me! LOL . I didn't realize they'd added this repeat mode though, I'll have to check it out again. Modern launchers mostly let you change the icon for shortcuts anyway.  B)

Comment: Accepted. Does what I want. The new UI is also very nice and clean! Still bugged by the icon tho. Ah... that should be the worst of my problems! lol

Comment: What about RTM? Did you give that a try as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the default calendar allows you to repeat events. The following repeat options exist:

- None
- Daily
- Weekly (every Sunday)
- Every 2 weeks (Sunday)
- Monthly (every last Sun)
- Monthly (on day 29)
- Yearly (on April 29)

NOTE: The dates are Sunday, because it's Sunday here.

Comment: No. None of those repeat options meet the requirements. Those are simply hardcoded repeats. I need it to dynamically adjust the repeat date based on the completion date.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Tasks Organizer Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinjasoft.tasks_trial) by Tinjasoft does that.

Answer (score 0):

[Any.do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo) is very good, easy to use, flexible and has postponable reminders.
They also have a [Cal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo.cal) extension.

> Millions use Any.do every day to remember all the tasks
>   they want to-do and make sure they get them done. Key benefits:
>   Seamless cloud sync, Speech recognition, Alerts, Any.do Moment, Snooze
>   tasks, Google Task Sync, Notes, Sub tasks, Amazing Widgets, Repeating
>   / Recurring Tasks, Missed call, Auto complete, In app actions, Gesture
>   support & much more!

Comment: Are you affiliated to Any.do by any chance, or just a happy user? If you are affiliated the rules of this site require you to mention this in your answer.

Comment: Happy user of course. Although I would like to be able to choose pospone time (you currently can only choose to pospone by 15m, 1h, 3h, tomorrow)

Comment: Last I checked though, it does not have the one requirement I really need, which is repeat interval based on **completion** date. If I complete the task early, the next reminder needs to come up 6 months earlier, from the date COMPLETED, not from the last due date. Unless they've since added this? I did always like the LOOK of any.do, it is beautiful, but I really do need this feature.